# not able to deploy contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I'm working on API'S for smart contract.  I'm using tronbox to compile and migrate. Error is this contract `constructor expected 1 arguments, received 0` I tried to add arguments in migrations like this but it's not working.

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage.sol');

module.exports = (deployer) => {
  const VALUE = 100;
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage)
    .then(() => (VALUE));
};
```

This is my contract.

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 public data;
    event UpdateData(uint256 oldValue, uint256 newValue, uint256 timestamp);
    constructor (uint256 _value) public {
        require(_value > 0, "in SimpleStorage:constructor(). Value must be greater than 0.");
        data = _value;
    }
    function updateData(uint256 _value) public {
        require(_value > 0, "in SimpleStorage:setData(). Value must be greater than 0.");
        emit UpdateData(data, _value, now);
        data = _value;
    }
    function getData() public view returns (uint256) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is my Controller

```
const updatedData = async (params) => {
  try {
    const { value, contractAddress } = params;
    const contractInstance = await getContractInstance(contractAddress);
    utils.setDefaultKeyAndAddressInTronWeb(process.env.TOF_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const result = await contractInstance.methods.updateData(value).send();
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      status: 'failure',
      message: e.message,
      data: [],
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The format to add constructor arguments for a Truffle migration script is described here: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-

So you need to use: `deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, VALUE)`